#  How to highlight a row in NSBrowser?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbrowser

I tried to highlight the rows in a `NSBrowser` using `selectRowIndexes` of the `NSBrowser`,but it does not highlight the rows.In 'NSTableView`rows can be highlighted using

```
 - [NSTableView selectRowIndexes:byExendingSelection:]

  - (void)selectRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes inColumn:(NSInteger).
```

Is there any api to highlight the rows in `NSBrowser`?  I would like to highlight the rows without a mouseclick on the browser,I have some known indexes I want to highlight these rows in my custom method.

Comment: Same issue here, no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the first five rows in the first column :

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,4)];
[myNSBrowser selectRowIndexes:indexes inColumn:0];
```

To select the fourth row in the first column :

```
[myNSBrowser selectRow:3 inColumn:0];
```

Comment: I dont see this as an answer. I'm having the same issue, an event happens i select the proper row/column, but there is no highlight, so the user feel as if i did not update selection ....